# Unable to debug using Vagrant with custom PHP 7.2 installed and VSCode using Firefox, VSCode fails to break into a breakpoint

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, vagrant, xdebug

In my project I have the following Xdebug settings on a Vagrant running VM:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_host=10.0.2.2
debug.repomote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
```

Whilst on VSCode I have set it up like that:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/home/vagrant/code": "${workspaceRoot}",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The xdebug settings are located into inside a vagrant vm whilst the ide is on the host. The host Ip (`10.0.2.2`) is provided via the command: `netstat -rn | grep "^0.0.0.0 " | cut -d " " -f10`

Then I enable the debugging on the Firefox using the `xdebug-helper` with the following settings:

[image: Xdebug helper settings]

But my IDE it fails to stop the execution on a breakpoint. Whilst debugging it I opened a shell session with the Vagrant running VM:

```
vagrant up && vagrant ssh
```

And then I test the reverse connection with it into the port 9000 using TCP protocol using the command (after having enabled the VSCode into listening for xdebug):

```
nc -z -v 10.0.2.2 9000
```

The command itself shows the message:

```
Connection to 10.0.2.2 9000 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

Also my `nginx.conf` says:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com;

    root /home/vagrant/code;

    index index.php index.html;

    charset utf-8;  

    keepalive_timeout 65;
    server_tokens off; 

    sendfile off;

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    proxy_buffer_size   128k;
    proxy_buffers   4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(?:css|cur|js|jpe?g|gif|htc|ico|png|html|xml|otf|ttf|eot|woff|svg)$ {
        access_log off;
        expires 30d;
        tcp_nodelay off;

        ## Set the OS file cache.
        open_file_cache max=3000 inactive=120s;
        open_file_cache_valid 45s;
        open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
        open_file_cache_errors off;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

And the `Vagrantfile` is the following:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
    config.vm.box_version = "20180917.0.0"
    config.vm.box_download_insecure = true

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.name = "example-website"

        vb.memory = 3072
        vb.cpus = 2

        vb.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--uartmode1", "disconnected" ]
    end

    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.80"
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8090
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 2922

    config.vm.synced_folder "./.", "/home/vagrant/code"

    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "./machine/provision/provision-xenial64.sh"
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "./machine/provision/provision-hosts.sh"
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "./machine/provision/provision-docker.sh"
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "./machine/provision/provision-nginx.sh"
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "./machine/provision/provision-php.sh"

    config.vm.provision :docker_compose, yml: "/home/vagrant/code/machine/docker_compose/cue.yml", run: "always"
end
```

Also the VSCode instance is a vscodium build as well and has the `felixfbecker.php-debug` plugin. Do you know why the VSCodium fails to break into a breakpoint?

Comment: 1) What Xdebug log has to say about such failed connection? Does it even tries to connect? Log is a must in troubleshooting. 2) What is `10.0.2.2` exactly? I just want to be sure that it's a correct IP address (misunderstanding what that host is used for / how Xdebug works is a quite common mistake).

Comment: 1) I find lo log file (even if I search for it)
2) It is the ip that the guest can communicate with rthe host as a result of the command `netstat -rn | grep "^0.0.0.0 " | cut -d " " -f10` running after I get the a shell session inside the vagrqant-launched vm.

Comment: 1) `xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log` -- that's the Xdebug log file. It has to be created if such entry is present. if it's not there, then Xdebug may not be even trying to connect. See if placing `xdebug_break();` in your code will make any changes in this regard.

Comment: 2) The IP must be an IP of the host OS (where VSCode is running) as seen from inside the VM .. as it's Xdebug that connects to IDE and not other way around). I'm not that much into Linux (your netstat/grep command), so make sure you are not connecting to some service in virtual OS (e.g. to php-fpm, that by default also uses TCP 9000 port). If you want to be on a safer side -- change ports for Xdebug to be something different, e.g. 9001 (less chances that this port is used by some service on "wrong" IP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the code actually being called?

Sometimes because of a frontend bug especially on ajax calling events your code it may not even called at all. So ensure first that your code is actually called and then try to figure out whether it is an xdebug issue.

So as seen the connection on xdebug from guest into host is being performed. And the ip is set correctly. So it is rather plausible for the piece of code that has the breakpoint not to be called at all, so the IDE does not break into the expected breakpoint.